# Автоматическая установка расширения через групповые политики

Tags: windows, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Скачал архив с шаблонами групповых политик из http://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip

Закинул chrome.admx и google.admx в C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions, также закинул файлы локализации в соответствующие папки

В редакторе локальной групповой политики(gpedit.msc) появились настройки для хрома, **вручную** задать нужные параметры теперь можно, но как сделать это **автоматически**?